# Check if a file belong to one of folders

Tags: .net, regex, c#-4.0

I have directories like

```
c:\test\data\product\delete\
c:\test\data\order\delete\
c:\test\data\quote\delete\
c:\temp\data\abc\delete\
c:\temp\data\pqr\delete\
c:\temp\data\xyz\delete\
```

and so on...

All `delete` folders contain some files.
The question is when I have a file, example:

```
c:\test\data\order\delete\order1.txt
```

I want to check whether it belongs to any of the directory above.

Is it possible with `Regex` or is there any better way to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`Regex` is not necessary in this case. You can do like bellow:

```
List<string> foldersList = new List<string>
{
    @"c:\test\data\product\delete\",
    @"c:\test\data\order\delete\",
    @"c:\test\data\quote\delete\",
    @"c:\temp\data\abc\delete\",
    @"c:\temp\data\pqr\delete\",
    @"c:\temp\data\xyz\delete\"
};
string file = @"c:\test\data\order\delete\order1.txt";

bool isChild = foldersList.Any(f => file.StartsWith(f));
```

Above code is case sensitive search. To search case-insensitive, you can do like bellow:

```
bool isChild = foldersList.Any(
    f => file.IndexOf(f, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0);
```

In case it must be `Regex`, you can do like bellow:

```
bool isChild = foldersList.Any(
    f => Regex.IsMatch(file, "^" + Regex.Escape(f), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
```

`^` mean match at the begin of string.

Comment: Thanks Sakura. Sorry, I forgot to mention that no of folders are not fixed. but have a pattern like  "c:\test\data\*\delete" and "c:\temp\data\*\delete"

Comment: Can you edit your question and add more info? I will edit my answer to fit your need.